# Stuck in History #1

Tags: riddle, history

A crowd blocks my view of the important one

As a loud sound tells me that man is done

A mysterious lady stands by in pictures taken

Then is never seen again like a strip of cooked bacon

So somehow I feel that as the decades go on

Some supposed CIA agents may go on the run

What historical event is this describing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A crowd blocks my view of the important one

> Lee Harvey Oswald, from a rooftop, shot Kennedy through a parade

As a loud sound tells me that man is done

> A gunshot and the gasps/screams of the crowd in Dallas

A mysterious lady stands by in pictures taken

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babushka_Lady

Then is never seen again like a strip of cooked bacon

> Nobody has ever identified her. @user75502 additionally notes that bacon might refer to the Bay of Pigs incident — thank you!

So somehow I feel that as the decades go on
Some supposed CIA agents may go on the run

> People have been making conspiracy theories that the CIA assassinated him

What historical event is this describing?

> The assassination of JFK

Comment: Lbh tbg gb vg whfg orsber V pbhyq. Nyfb "fgevc bs pbbxrq onpba" pbhyq or n ersrerapr gb gur Onl bs Cvtf Vainfvba. "Fbzr fhccbfrq PVN ntragf znl tb ba gur eha" zvtug or gbb.

Comment: It's weird, but as soon as I started reading the text, this event is the first that came to my mind.

Comment: Mine too, and I'm guessing also El-Guest's. This is usually not a sign of a good riddle :-).

Comment: I'll try to be more cryptic next time. Also, I'm new here.

Comment: @XStanton, you may be interested in [these questions/answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation+riddle) about riddle creation

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan you read my mind! :-)